# What is the use of [i] in the below code?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
var word= readLine()!!.toString()
var letter:Char='a'
println(CharCount(word,'a'))

}

fun CharCount(word:String, letter:Char):Int{
var a=0
var b=word
var length=b.length
for (i in 0 .. length-1){
    if (letter==b[i]) {
        a++
        }
    }
return a

}
```

Note: If someone please help to explain for loop part of this code like why we use [i] or what is it use? and a++ role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are character arrays. Here the `i` goes from 0 to the length of the word (minus 1), practically iterating through the word's letters. Here the [i] as the current cell position within the array marks the (i+1)th letter of the word. This part of code counts the occurrence of the letter `letter` in the word `word`. The function compares each letter of the word with its second parameter. Every time there is a match `a` is incremented by 1. In the end `a` returns how many times said letter is present in the word.

Comment: Thank you I got everything except this part (letter==b[i])). What is the meaning of putting [i] with variable B.

Comment: In this context the variable `b` is handled an array of characters instead of one string literal. For example if the input word is "Kotlin", then `b` will be { 'K', 'o', 't', 'l', 'i', 'n' }. An array has positions and values. By certain standards the numbering of the positions in an array starts from 0 (see `var a=0`). Then `b[0]` is `K`, `b[1]` is `o`, `b[2]` is `t` etc. The [i] simply means that we're taking the character at the (i + 1)th position: `[0]` is the 1st position, so `b[0]` is the character at the 1st position, `[1]` is the 2nd position, so `b[1]` is the 2nd character etc.